# stackoverflowerror and manifest attribute android:launchmode

Tags: android, xml, stack-overflow

Okay, I have created a program, but when I get to running it I previously had no problems. Now I get the stackoverflowerror when running it. The problem occurs in my tabactivities. In one of my tabs, you can open activities within it. The error is only produces when I navigate inside that tab.

Can you please take a look at my code and let me know what I am doing wrong.

Here is an example of my manifest activity declaration:

```
<activity
        android:name=".EarlyStrat"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:label="info2"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
    </activity>
```

Here is a declaration of the one of the xml files that seem to cause the error:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/arrowyes"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/backarrow" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/returns"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/newsbutton"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="click here to RETURN"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Early Strategy"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/onebgr"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" > (there is more code after this and it is nested as well)...
```

and the xml code goes on...

is there any recommendations and/or can you point me to where I might find the information?

Comment: did you add tabactivities to the manifest ?

Comment: Stackoverflow usually indicates an endless recursion. It is very unlikely that some layout would cause it. Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: @talhakosen, yes the tab activities are in the manifest. 

In response to Henry, I am currently at work, but I can definitely post it later. In the meantime I went on and tried a different approach and that approach worked but it didn't solve the initial problem which I still want to solve, so yes I will post the code later today. Thanks!